# R: Counting Observations in Bins

Tags: r

I have the following dataset in R:

```
library(dplyr)

set.seed(123)
n <- 100
country <- sample(c("USA", "Canada", "UK"), n, replace = TRUE)
gender <- sample(c("M", "F"), n, replace = TRUE)
age <- sample(18:100, n, replace = TRUE)
height <- runif(n, min = 150, max = 180)
owns_bicycle <- sample(c("Yes", "No"), n, replace = TRUE)

df <- data.frame(country, gender, age, height, owns_bicycle)
```

**My Problem:**

- First, I want to break height into 5 equal sized groups by value of their height (e.g. 0%-20%, 20%-40%, etc.)
- Next, I want to break age into 5 equal sized groups by value of their age (e.g. 0%-20%, 20%-40%, etc.)
- Then, for each unique combination of country, gender, age_group and height_group, I want to find out the percent of who own a bicycle.
- As a result, this type of analysis would let me know things like - "if you are a man between ages 30-35, between 150-155 cm and from USA, there is a 43% chance you own a bicycle".
- Just to clarify - each person should only be in a single group. And each group should roughly have the same number of people.

Here is my R code that I wrote:

```
final = df %>%
  mutate(height_group = cut(height, breaks = 5),
         age_group = cut(age, breaks = 5)) %>%
  group_by(country, gender, height_group, age_group) %>%
  summarise(count = n(),
            percent_own_bicycle = mean(owns_bicycle == "Yes") * 100)
```

**Can someone please tell me if I have done this correctly?**

```
> final
# A tibble: 67 x 6
# Groups:   country, gender, height_group [29]
   country gender height_group age_group   count percent_own_bicycle
   <chr>   <chr>  <fct>        <fct>       <int>               <dbl>
 1 Canada  F      (151,157]    (34.2,50.4]     4                  25
 2 Canada  F      (151,157]    (66.6,82.8]     2                   0
 3 Canada  F      (157,162]    (17.9,34.2]     2                   0
 4 Canada  F      (157,162]    (34.2,50.4]     1                 100
 5 Canada  F      (157,162]    (50.4,66.6]     2                   0
 6 Canada  F      (157,162]    (82.8,99.1]     1                   0
 7 Canada  F      (162,168]    (82.8,99.1]     2                  50
 8 Canada  F      (168,174]    (17.9,34.2]     3                   0
 9 Canada  F      (168,174]    (34.2,50.4]     1                 100
10 Canada  F      (174,180]    (17.9,34.2]     1                   0
# ... with 57 more rows
# i Use `print(n = ...)` to see more rows
```

Thanks!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Be careful when asking questions of the type ["is my code correct"](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/298303/is-it-allowed-to-ask-if-my-code-is-correct-in-stack-overflow).

Having said that, your code seems great! But, `cut()` with an integer `breaks` argument isn't what you want. From it's help page:

> When breaks is specified as a single number, the range of the data is
> divided into breaks pieces of equal length

So it isn't separating your data by its distribution, but just based on its range. You want to use `quantile()` to find the breaks. See the difference:

```
> cut(df$height, 5) %>% levels()
[1] "(151,157]" "(157,162]" "(162,168]" "(168,174]" "(174,180]"
> cut(df$height, breaks = quantile(df$height, seq(0, 1, 0.2))) %>% levels()
[1] "(151,156]" "(156,160]" "(160,167]" "(167,174]" "(174,180]"

> cut(df$age, 5) %>% levels()
[1] "(17.9,34.2]" "(34.2,50.4]" "(50.4,66.6]" "(66.6,82.8]" "(82.8,99.1]"
> cut(df$age, breaks = quantile(df$age, seq(0, 1, 0.2))) %>% levels()
[1] "(18,31]"     "(31,45.2]"   "(45.2,62.4]" "(62.4,78.4]" "(78.4,99]"
```

Applying it to your code:

```
df %>%
  mutate(height_group = cut(height, breaks = quantile(height, seq(0, 1, 0.2))),
         age_group = cut(age, breaks = quantile(age, seq(0, 1, 0.2)))) %>%
  group_by(country, gender, height_group, age_group) %>%
  summarise(count = n(),
            percent_own_bicycle = mean(owns_bicycle == "Yes") * 100) 

# A tibble: 75 × 6
# Groups:   country, gender, height_group [31]
   country gender height_group age_group   count percent_own_bicycle
   <chr>   <chr>  <fct>        <fct>       <int>               <dbl>
 1 Canada  F      (151,156]    (31,45.2]       3                33.3
 2 Canada  F      (151,156]    (62.4,78.4]     1                 0  
 3 Canada  F      (151,156]    (78.4,99]       1                 0  
 4 Canada  F      (156,160]    (18,31]         2                 0  
 5 Canada  F      (156,160]    (31,45.2]       1               100  
 6 Canada  F      (156,160]    (62.4,78.4]     1                 0  
 7 Canada  F      (156,160]    (78.4,99]       1                 0  
 8 Canada  F      (160,167]    (45.2,62.4]     1                 0  
 9 Canada  F      (160,167]    (78.4,99]       1                 0  
10 Canada  F      (167,174]    (18,31]         3                 0  
# ℹ 65 more rows
# ℹ Use `print(n = ...)` to see more rows
```

Comment: @ Ricardo Semião e Castro: Thank you so much for your kind answer! Will the approach you have used roughly ensure that each group has the same number of people? e.g. height 151-156 and 160-167 roughly  have the same number of people? thank you so much!

Comment: You're welcome! Yes it will, whereas `breaks = 5` didn't. You can check that by doing `table(final$age_group)` and table(final$height_group)

Answer (score 0):

Using the logic given in the answer provided by @Ricardo Semião e Castro, here is a solution based on the data.table library:

```
library(data.table)

dt = data.table(df)
data_table_result = dt[, `:=`(height_group = cut(height, breaks = quantile(height, seq(0, 1, 0.2))),
          age_group = cut(age, breaks = quantile(age, seq(0, 1, 0.2))))][
              , .(count = .N,
                  percent_own_bicycle = mean(owns_bicycle == "Yes") * 100),
              by = .(country, gender, height_group, age_group)]
```